# How can I use page-wide threepart table in a 2 column document?

Tags: tables, footnotes, ieeetran, threeparttable

I have an IEEEtran paper I am writing and I want to insert a table with footnotes that spans over the whole page width.

Normally to insert a table over the two columns I use the table* environment and everything works well, however, to inclue a footnote at the bottom of a table I use the threeparttable environment, which does not support the * "option" and so I cannot use it in this case.

I have searched online and could not find anyone with the same requirment as I am facing and therefore could not find a suitable solution.

Does anyone have a suggestions of how I could acomplish this?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[0-3]

\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{p{10cm}cc}
        a$^\dag$ & b & c \\
        a        & b & c \\
        a        & b & c \\
        a        & b & c \\
        a        & b & c \\
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item \textbf{\dag~This is a footnote}    
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\lipsum[0-5]
\end{document}
```

Edit:
Just to clarify, what I was trying to do was to use `threeparttable*` instead of `table*`, which I now have learned (thanks to the answers below) that does not make sense.
Instead I should have used `threeparttable` nested within a `table*` environment, which behaves as needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you sure that your claim that a `threeparttable` environment cannot be used inside a `table*` environment is correct?

Comment: The line `\item \textbf{\dag~This is a footnote}` may generate an error. If you write `\item[$\dag$] This is a footnote`, you should be ok.

Comment: @Mico That was not my claim, I was using `threeparttable*` (which does not exist) instead of `threeparttable` and not using `table` or `table*` at all. Thanks for your answer and for the clarification.

Comment: Many thanks for providing this clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a reason for any incompatibility between `table*` and `threeparttable` in a two-column environment, as long as you use `\tnote` and `\item` in the `tablenotes` environment properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{A 21-column table}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{20}{c}}
    \hline
        a\tnote{$\dag$} & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c \\
        a       & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c \\
        a       & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c \\
        a       & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c \\
        a       & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c & b & c \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[$\dag$] This is a footnote.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-20] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, it worked perfectly. I was replacing the table environment by the threeparttable one, I didn't know I could use them both together.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @jpnadas - Longtable and table are incompatible, but threeparttable is more like a minipage with a caption and numbered footnotes.

Comment: @JohnKormylo gotcha.... thanks for the explanation, it can be a bit confusing if you come to think of it, cause I always viewed them both as just "tables", but it makes sense now that I know the difference...

Answer (score 0):

You have the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[0-3]
\begin{strip}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{p{10cm}cc}
        a$^\dag$ & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
        a & b & c \\
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item \textbf{\dag~This is a footnote}
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{strip}

\lipsum[0-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works for what I need. I would like to point out that using the table* also works, as per the answer from Mico.
But this is also an alternative!

Comment: The difference it that it is not a float (if you want  caption, you have to use `\captionof{table}{Some caption}`. By default, `table*` is placed at the top of the next page. It can be placed at the bottom of the current page with package `stfloats` (same author as `cuted`)

Comment: Interesting, I will keep a note for that in case I need something like this in the future.. Thank you.