# Spanning table across two column makes footnote invisible

Tags: tables, overleaf, springernature

The [submission guidelines](https://www.springer.com/journal/41060/submission-guidelines#Instructions%20for%20Authors_References) for Springer Nature specify using a two-column format. The provided [Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq) suggests using `table*` to span a table across two columns. However, when I implement this, the content within `\footnotetext` disappears while `\footnotemark` is retained, as shown in the image below.

**Could someone kindly explain why this is happening and how to correct it?**

CODE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%% Standard Packages
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
%%%%

%%%% user-defined packages
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % subcaption is not compatible with ieee template so instead use this
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for bib german words \citep{szczkesna2023datasets}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % to ventre the table caption when spanned across two columns
%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{fgklblfglkbgr dklfmglkmdfklg kldmfklgmldkf ml;dfmgf ,d;lmgermdf;l}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{dfdf} & \textbf{dfg} & \textbf{erfgfr} & \textbf{srfg}\footnotemark[1] \\
\hline
sdgdge              & 5  &  No   & gfgfgf \\
rdfger              & 5  &  Yes  & gfgffb  \\
sdgerg              & 15 &  Yes  & bfbgt \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext[1]{s;lfmer;l el;rmg;ler lermgpler mlfmv lermg;lrem merl;mg;lr lermgl;rm;p g;lermgkl;rem}
\label{tab:sgdrgergt}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

GENERATED TABLE:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable: Which document class do you employ, and which packages do you load?

Comment: I believe that, behind the scenes, the springer class uses the threeparttable for its table environment, but hasn't done the same for the table* env (from what I can tell). So, instead you can explicitly use the threeparttable syntax and get the expected result. See the answer here for an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490782/205904

Comment: @Mico Code added. However, it would be more helpful if you can see the overleaf template as it has its own declared class definition.